Who did the animation for the season 1 intros of Caroline in the City?
The first ten or twelve episodes of the sitcom Caroline in the City began with brief animations of the cartoon drawn by the titular Caroline - does anyone know who drew/animated these shorts?

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111910/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cst_sm

The show's cartoonist was Bonnie Timmons. Whenever you see Caroline's comic strip in the show, Timmons would provide the artwork.
The animation for the opening credits (and at the start of each episode for the first season) was done by a small NYC-based studio called The Ink Tank, based on designs provided to them by Timmons.

For several years The Ink Tank had good gig with CBS Entertainment doing animation for the NBC broadcast "Caroline in the City".
The first season had regular opens of full animation.
The title card (created for the pilot) was animated by Ed Smith after designs by Bonnie Timmons. The remaining full opens were animated by Kris van Alphen.  He had been recommended by Paul Dreissen.  For most of the run he animated from his home in Belgium.
We'd get the scripts from Los Angeles, send the boards to Europe and receive animation drawings via DHL back in New York.
After the first season, it became clear that a new opening in full drawn animation wasn't the most cost effective production policy.
The producers cut back to animated establishing shots.  These were usually building exteriors with bits of animation, walks mostly or passing cars.  That animation was largely done by Igor Mitrovic.   This went on for maybe 4 or 5 more years under the direct supervision of Nina Crews, then Shawn Atkins.
Ace And Sons Pictures - Official Blog





“4 or 5 more years”? The show had four seasons, so it can only have gone on for three more years (first season not included).

@Darren - '95-'99, so it was approx 4 years. There might also have been small editing changes when the show went into syndication and when the show was released as a box set
